# Programmatically importing an existing project into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to importing the project to eclipse through programmatically. I dont want to use UI mode.

Below is the code I used for importing the project:

```
IProjectDescription description = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().loadProjectDescription(  new Path("PROJECT_PATH/.project"));
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(description.getName());
project.create(description, null);
project.open(null);
```

I'm getting only the project folder along with `.location file`, `.markers.snap` file and `.syncinfo.snap` files, but I am not getting the source folder and etc.

Comment: Are you sure that the project that you are importing is already a java project? ie- is there a pre-existing .project file and does it have the java nature and java builder in it?

Comment: do you want to create a new project with its own set of files or do you want the workspace to point to the existing project?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `org.eclipse.ui.wizards.datatransfer.ImportOperation`

Try something like this:

```
IOverwriteQuery overwriteQuery = new IOverwriteQuery() {
        public String queryOverwrite(String file) { return ALL; }
};

String baseDir = // location of files to import
ImportOperation importOperation = new ImportOperation(project.getFullPath(),
        new File(baseDir), FileSystemStructureProvider.INSTANCE, overwriteQuery);
importOperation.setCreateContainerStructure(false);
importOperation.run(new NullProgressMonitor());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing a line with

```
description.setLocation(new Path("/absolute/path/to/project/folder"));
```

Comment: Nice! It will set the local file path as the location for the described project instead of the default workspace's path.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine. What do you exactly mean by you couldn't get the source folder? Have you tried to refresh the project?

`project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, new NullProgressMonitor());`

Comment: Yes. Not getting the source folder

Comment: Well if you don't provide further source code (get source folder code), I won't be able to help you.