# Dynamically load/import existing projects into workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to create my own RCP application and I have a problem. I try to load existing projects into workspace in "Project explorer" part like this:

[image: project explorer]

```
public class ProjectExplorerPart {
    IWorkspaceRoot root= ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

    final IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                IPath projectDotProjectFile = new Path("/media/flashx/TestProjectImport" + "/.project");
                IProjectDescription projectDescription = workspace.loadProjectDescription(projectDotProjectFile);
                IProject project = workspace.getRoot().getProject(projectDescription.getName());
                JavaCapabilityConfigurationPage.createProject(project, projectDescription.getLocationURI(), null);
            } catch (CoreException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

But there is no result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12401297/2670892

Comment: I tried with this method and it does not work :/

Comment: I reworded some of your problem explanation, removed "thanks" and removed commented code from your code block. "There is no result" is not really explaining the problem. Can you go into detail? Also, what about the solution that greg provided doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to implement your own view through Custom Navigator Framework, no ?

If so, try this [tutorial](https://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-7-creating-a-custom-navigator/) 
I can't explain to you every step here in this post, but it's a long long way to go....

It's probably better to re-use the package explorer or project explorer believe me. So that you can have all the menu and actions available without overriding them. You can create your own custom project nature if that fit your need.