# How to invoke importwizard from eclipse plugin programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I need to invoke eclipse importwizard from the eclipse plugin project programmatically. i follow the example from , seems not work
https://resheim.net/2010/07/invoking-eclipse-wizard.html

then in my code , it shows wizards array is empty, do i need to register importwizard ? and how?

```
IWizardDescriptor[] wizards= PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getImportWizardRegistry().getPrimaryWizards();
```

Comment: Which import wizard do you want to show? The import dialog doesn't have any 'primary' wizards, you need to know the id of the wizard.

Comment: i need to use import existing project into workspace (but without copying source code into eclipse workspace)

Answer (score 2):

The import dialog doesn't use 'primary' wizards. You need to know the id of the wizard you want to use and call the wizard registry `findWizard` method.

The Import Projects wizard id is `org.eclipse.ui.wizards.import.ExternalProject` so the code would look like:

```java
String id = "org.eclipse.ui.wizards.import.ExternalProject"
IWizardDescriptor descriptor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getImportWizardRegistry().findWizard(id);
IWizard wizard = descriptor.createWizard();
WizardDialog wd = new WizardDialog(display.getActiveShell(), wizard);
wd.setTitle(wizard.getWindowTitle());
wd.open();
```

Comment: thanks i will try it out. i found there seems to be also another way ,it is without GUI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401297/programmatically-importing-an-existing-project-into-eclipse

Comment: i tried your suggested way ,but got null point exception at descriptor.createWizard(); seems descriptor is not found/created. do i have to do some setting in plugin  to register import wizard?

Comment: There was a space by mistake in the `id` line of the code - should be `org.eclipse.ui.wizards.import.ExternalProject` (no spaces)

Comment: Thanks it works , ImportWizard is invoked successfully, one more thing, how to programmatically select the projects instead of select projects manually?

Comment: I don't think there is an API to do that. You would have to examine the individual wizard source to see if there is anything that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

private void openProject(String projectfolder) throws CoreException {
        //TODO: check if project is already created and open, if yes do nothing or just refresh

```
    IProjectDescription description = null;
    IProject project = null;
    description = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().loadProjectDescription(
            new Path(new File(projectfolder).getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/.project"));
    project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
            .getProject(description.getName());
    project.create(description, null);

    project.open(null);

}
```